# Magento - Filtering a category by size

Tags: magento, size, filtering, categories

Hi is see various code blocks for filtering catergories.

But i haven't seen anything for what i am looking for.

We gonna sell kidsclothing in our webshop.
Kidsclothing can be dived in 4 different size blocks (baby, toddler, enfant and kids) and each block has different sizes.

Like:

Size block - Sizes
Baby - 50, 56, 62, 68 and 74
Toddler - 80, 86, 92 and 98
Enfant - 104, 110, 116 and 122
Kids - 128, 134, 140, 146, 152, 158, 164, 170, 176

Now i put these the right sizes into the right categories (like baby).
But only when i have a product that spans multple size blocks there a more size visible than i would like to see ...

For example.
When i have a configurable product with the following sizes 56, 74, 86 and 98.
The sizes 86 and 98 shouldn't be visible in the baby size block ... and the 56 and 74 shouldn't be visible in the toddler size block.

Who can help me write a code for this?

I have magento 1.6.2 CE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to split your configurable product for every age category. 
So you will have more products (consider this as minus).
But from the other hand you will be able to
 1. Set different images for child, toddler, enfant (shoes does look different for all of them)
 2. Set different prices for every age category.
 3. More possibilities on creating price rules.

Comment: the other big minus is that people can't see if there is a bigger size in a other size block ...
(only on the product page)

Comment: they will if you leave products as is.
But customizing filters that way is pretty bad idea.

Comment: Basicly what i need is to hide some values when selecting a category
when catogory a is selected only values 1-5 are visible from the size attribute
When slect cat a, show attribute ID 1-5 or hide 6-20

when catogory b is selected only values 6-11 are visible from the size attribute
When slect cat b, show attribute ID 6-11 or hide 1-5 and 12-20

Comment: You just don't realize how configurable product and filtering are implemented.
Configurable product is filtered by category, simple - by their attributes. Adding your logic will cost your performance, that is critical for magento.

Comment: Custom, likely in php :) I don't like the logic you want to implement so I'm not interested in implementing it for you.

Comment: hi sergy,
what isn't logic in your opinion?
In basic the categories in combination with the attributes will do.
But we also have shirts in all sizes (from baby to kid). And we don't want to show the kid sizes in the baby group.